# Exit bash function for case of no arguments

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following bash function.  I want to exit the function and skip the `awk` commands when no arguments are passed to the function.  What can I do?

Would there be a problem for injection attacks if I use `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, should they somehow be set to attacker-controlled values ?

```
wapi-lseq ()
 {
  ## Print text with colour according to line number position
  (( $# == 0 )) && printf '%s\n' "See 'firefly-wapi-kcard-klue'"

  awk -v ctp="$1" -v rst="$2" -v lseq="$3"  \
    'BEGIN {
        ## Store LNUM sequence as index to array laggr
        fm1="%s%s%s\n" ; fm2="%s\n"
        n = split(lseq, a, ",")
        for ( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ ) laggr[a[i]]
      }

     {
       ## When NR is an index in array, use colour sequence ctp
       if (NR in laggr) printf(fm1, ctp, $0, rst)
       else printf(fm2, $0)
     }'

 }  # wapi-lseq ends here
```

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I have no clue about possible injection attacks.

Comment: Generally, injection attacks are a problem when your awk code is not a constant string, or when you use `system()` or a `|` inside your awk code. I don't see anything that looks like a code smell here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to piggyback off the current number-of-args test (`$# == 0`), eg:

```
wapi-lseq ()
 {
# (( $# == 0 )) && printf '%s\n' "See 'firefly-wapi-kcard-klue'" && return
#                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
# or: per Charles Duffy's comment:
 (( $# == 0 )) && { printf '%s\n' "See 'firefly-wapi-kcard-klue'"; return; }

  awk -v ctp="$1" -v rst="$2" -v lseq="$3"
    ... rest of awk script ...

 }  # wapi-lseq ends here
```

**NOTE:** if you use `exit` (as opposed to `return`) then you'll actually `exit` the parent process

---

If the parent process needs to see a 'success/fail' return code then consider that in `bash` a `0` return code is considered 'success' while a non-zero return code is considered 'fail'.

One idea for modifying the current function to return a 'success/fail' return code:

```
wapi-lseq ()
 {
# (( $# == 0 )) && printf '%s\n' "See 'firefly-wapi-kcard-klue'" && return 1
#                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ (fail)
# or: per Charles Duffy's comment:
 (( $# == 0 )) && { printf '%s\n' "See 'firefly-wapi-kcard-klue'"; return 1; }

  awk -v ctp="$1" -v rst="$2" -v lseq="$3"
    ... rest of awk script ...

  return 0
# ^^^^^^^^ (success)
 }  # wapi-lseq ends here
```

**NOTES:**

- the `return 0` will insure the function always returns `0`
- if you remove the `return 0` then the function will return whatever return value is generated by the last command in the function (in this case the `awk` command)

Comment: Do you really want to skip the return should the `printf` somehow fail?

Comment: Better practice to make it `(( $# == 0 )) && { printf ...; return 1; }`

Comment: BTW, if you leave out the explicit `return 0`, the function will just return `$?`, the exit status of awk, which is probably appropriate; that way we'll reflect if the script has an error reading input / writing output, or is run with an awk that doesn't support syntax it's written to expect, &c. Typically a bad idea to force an exit status of 0 unless you're certain the preceding commands _really did_ succeed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I was batting around the idea of going into more details on what's returned by a normal function sans the final `return`; I've updated the answer, again; thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can  try something like this :

```
{m,g,n}awk -v \__="$#" 'BEGIN { if (!+__) {  
                                            exit } 
                        } /...pattern..../ { 
                                      "action....." }'
```

so instead of trying to deal with `"$#"` at the shell function level, directly pass it through to `awk`

and to answer your 2nd concern, your code itself would neither create a security hole, nor detect an existing one.

`eval()`-type functions have caused untold scores of security hole headaches at other scripting languages - thank goodness `awk` doesn't have that other than `system()` - so treat this feature with care.

Comment: Alas, `system()` isn't the _only_ way; awk (at least GNU awk) also has popen() equivalents via the `|` operator.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : you also wanna tell me sun is hot and sky is blue ? But speaking of `print … | …` i've built this small custom function to bypass the lack of `|&` in `non-gawk`s and have it print up to like `500 MB` data out to pipe, process by external utilities, *AND* getline back the results all in one shot, without needing needing any temp space, temp files, shell variables, shell arrays, fudging with environment, or use `FIFO`s.

Comment: othis answer does say "doesn't have that other than `system()`"; that seems like a pretty black-and-white assertion that `popen()` doesn't exist. If I misinterpreted that assertion, please accept my apologies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : which `awk` allows any user code directly call `popen()` ? you mean just print data to pipe for execution ? Even that isn't an `awk` issue, since the hacker is already inside your system in order to first provide `awk` with nefariously crafted data to be fed downstream. And that was my point - `awk` rarely creates any extra security holes (other than that busybox BS that's costantly showing up on CVE list), but at the same time, it's also the wrong tool for detection of existing holes/intruders

Comment: Yes, using `|` to invoke `popen()` is an explicit decision to do something dangerous, but so is using `system()`; in both cases, the commands being run need to be constructed carefully (and I've seen too many people use string concatenation in this kind of context). I agree that using awk carefully/correctly is generally not insecure, but "carefully" needs to be defined not only to include avoiding `system()` with non-constant strings, but also to avoid using the pipe operator to invoke `popen()` with a non-constant string; and _that's_ the point I was trying to make above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : you're that callous in your programming style using dynamically constructed strings for `system()` is something you need to avoid ?

Comment: Hmm? This is a teaching resource. Part of what we should be teaching people is where the pitfalls / landmines are at. Just because you or I already know not to do something doesn't absolve us from the need to teach our readers not to do it; it's declining to show readers where the broken stairs / hazards are that I'd call more rightfully describable as "callous".

Comment: so you describing `popen()` so misleadingly, implying it's actually a function name one can call instead of printing to the pipe with onward commands, which is rather similar to placing the pipe just after  `awk` and piping stuff downstream, instead of being inside and into a posix shell (as opposed to calling `system()`, which takes a lot of effort to print lots of data into before executing cmds, and u easily get back the exit code (compared to the contortion required to get the exit code back into awk from a print to pipe cmd) is what u consider "teaching people" ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : "teaching people" …… definitely no irony lost coming from the one who "teaches" others to sort first before filtering instead of the other way around.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : i was talking about string concat inside `awk` to generate commands and you're somehow you went off a tangent and talked about string concat at the shell level to generate commands.

Comment: I referred to `popen()` _talking to you_. I assume you know the underlying C functions behind the constructs; perhaps I shouldn't have done you that courtesy. But yes, it was a tangent _because you'd made a statement about `system()` being the only place awk was particularly prone to injection attacks_; I intended only to reply to that statement, distinct from larger context. Honestly, I wonder if you're interpreting everything I say as an attack, even when it's intended to be helpful.

Comment: And no, I don't agree that a pipe within awk code is similar to a downstream pipe in bash. The pipe in awk is converting data to code, and doesn't provide means to pass data as arguments safely; a downstream pipe in bash has bash's awareness of the distinction between syntax and data, and performs parameter expansions to inject variables' values only after parsing out shell syntax is complete. _In practice_, we see people unsafely constructing shell commands in awk this way, where in bash to reach similar levels of unsafety they'd need to call `eval`, run `sh -c "...$variable..."`, etc.

Comment: (contrast to the comment on the question where I talk about using _"`|` inside your own code"_ -- that's a less-technical audience, so I don't expect people there to know standard libc calls; but I've at least had it in my head that you're an experienced regular who knows what they're about; that's in keeping with the idea the question is general-audience, answers are general-audience, but comments directed at individuals are sidebars amongst ourselves).